# Is there any single font which support all Indian language in all android devices?

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to implement an app which support all Indian language.is there any single font which support all Indian Language?

Comment: Unfortunately no...... You have to impement them seperately. But I have heard a font named apara can be used to do this developed by a software expert.

Comment: I have used this font but it is not working for panjabi,Gujarati and oriya text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you ca use SakalBharati.ttf font file.

You can download this file from here [download link](http://tdil-dc.in/index.php?option=com_up-download&task=view-download-tool&view=download&toolid=805)